# Creando una firma HMAC sha256 con Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, hash, sha256, signature

necesito ayuda con este problema. Quiero crear una firma con los algoritmos HMAC y sha256.
En PHP es:

`$cadena = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11%3A11%3A11%2B00%3A00&UserID=look%40me.com&Version=1.0';
$clave = 'b1bdb357ced10fe4e9a69840cdd4f0e9c03d77fe';
rawurlencode(hash_hmac('sha256', $cadena, $clave, false));`

Este código genera la firma:

`3ceb8ed91049dfc718b0d2d176fb2ed0e5fd74f76c5971f34cdab48412476041`

El hecho es que debo hacerlo con Javascript puro y ahí encuentro que, con los mismos valores de cadena y clave, la firma generada es distinta:

`let firma = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(cadena, clave);
let base64 = firma.toString(CryptoJS.enc.hex);`

Para ello usé la librería:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/hmac-sha256.min.js"></script>`

Firma:
`af2943cd9b2bc960b02a4f4a992fedd2ffe849ac5e9e82bb1bd822d4d75f55be`

He leído mucha documentación desde la documentación oficial del sitio web que me solicita la firma, también he visto que en Node js hay librerías mucho más documentadas, pero debo hacerlo con Javascript, por favor cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Al parecer el problema está en la implementación que tienes de tu cadena en PHP, y lo que tratas de replicar en Javascript.

Tienes la siguiente cadena de entrada:

```
'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11%3A11%3A11%2B00%3A00&UserID=look%40me.com&Version=1.0'
```

La cual a simple vista es una URI codificada, es decir, ciertos caracteres han sido codificados para ser reemplazados por secuencias UTF-8.

Luego en PHP tienes lo siguiente:

```
rawurlencode(hash_hmac('sha256', $cadena, $clave, false));
```

Analicemos un momento esta línea.

Realizas el proceso de [`hash`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash) de tu cadena, pasando el `digest`, el secreto y le dices que la salida sean dígitos hexadecimales en minúsculas.

Luego, a esa salida le aplicas la función [`rawurldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rawurldecode.php), cosa a la cual no le encuentro sentido.

El resultado obtenido es:

```
'3ceb8ed91049dfc718b0d2d176fb2ed0e5fd74f76c5971f34cdab48412476041'
```

Si no aplicamos la función `rawurldecode` el código queda:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $cadena, $clave, false);
```

Si mostramos la salida de dicho comando, el resultado es:

```
'3ceb8ed91049dfc718b0d2d176fb2ed0e5fd74f76c5971f34cdab48412476041'
```

Sorpresa, la función `rawurldecode` no afecta para nada el resultado del `hash` cuando la aplicas sobre el mismo `hash`, pero veamos que pasa si la aplicamos sobre la cadena original (que viene codificada) y luego calculamos el `hash`:

```php
$clave = 'b1bdb357ced10fe4e9a69840cdd4f0e9c03d77fe';
$cadena = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11%3A11%3A11%2B00%3A00&UserID=look%40me.com&Version=1.0';
$decoded = rawurldecode($cadena);
hash_hmac('sha256', $decoded, $clave, false);
```

El resultado del código anterior es:

```
'af2943cd9b2bc960b02a4f4a992fedd2ffe849ac5e9e82bb1bd822d4d75f55be'
```

Interesante, coincide con el valor de `hash` que calculas con Javascript. Si mostramos la cadena decodificada (`echo $decoded`) esto es lo que tenemos:

```
'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11:11:11+00:00&UserID=look@me.com&Version=1.0'
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Según yo lo veo tienes 2 opciones:

1. Usar la cadena sin codificar y calcular el `hash` con Javascript
2. Calcular el hash sobre la cadena codificada.

Esto producirá 2 resultados diferentes, ya que la cadena decodificada no es igual a la cadena codificada en este caso.

En tu pregunta dices que necesitas el `hash` que ya obtienes con PHP. Aunque tu metodología no es la correcta (ya vimos porqué).

Intuyo, por el resultado que dices obtener en Javascript, que la cadena que pasas para calcular el `hash` no viene codificada. Para nosotros los programadores puede tener el mismo significado una cadena codificada que una decodificada, pero para un proceso de `hash` son cadenas totalmente diferentes.

La solución es escoger sobre qué tipo de cadena vas a realizar el `hash`.

Supongamos que deseo realizar el `hash` sobre una cadena no codificada (o decodificada).

En PHP lo tenemos así:

```php
$clave = 'b1bdb357ced10fe4e9a69840cdd4f0e9c03d77fe';
$cadena = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11%3A11%3A11%2B00%3A00&UserID=look%40me.com&Version=1.0';
$decoded = rawurldecode($cadena);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $decoded, $clave, false);
echo $hash;
```

El resultado:

```
'af2943cd9b2bc960b02a4f4a992fedd2ffe849ac5e9e82bb1bd822d4d75f55be'
```

En Javascript, no hace falta decodificar la cadena. (Asumo que la misma la pasas sin codificar):

```js
const clave = 'b1bdb357ced10fe4e9a69840cdd4f0e9c03d77fe';
let cadena = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11:11:11+00:00&UserID=look@me.com&Version=1.0';
let firma = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(cadena, clave);
let base64 = firma.toString(CryptoJS.enc.hex);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `<small>${base64}</small>`;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha256-6rXZCnFzbyZ685/fMsqoxxZz/QZwMnmwHg+SsNe+C/w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center" id="output"><div>
```

Claramente ambos resultados son coincidentes, ya que estamos aplicando la misma función `hash` con los mismos parámetros, sobre la misma cadena.

Ahora, imaginemos que deseamos calcular el `hash` sobre una cadena codificada.

En PHP basta con **no usar** el método **`rawurldecode`**, pero en Javascript debemos codificar la cadena si la misma no la tenemos o no la recibimos codificada.

En Javascript tenemos el método [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURI) y el método [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent).

Veamos ambos en acción sobre la cadena no codificada:

```js
let resultadoDeseado = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11%3A11%3A11%2B00%3A00&UserID=look%40me.com&Version=1.0';

let cadena = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11:11:11+00:00&UserID=look@me.com&Version=1.0';

//usando encodeURI
let encoded1 = encodeURI(cadena);
console.log(encoded1);
console.log(`¿Es encoded1 === resultadoDeseado? ${encoded1 === resultadoDeseado}`);

//usando encodeURIComponent
let encoded2 = encodeURIComponent(cadena);
console.log(encoded2);
console.log(`¿Es encoded2 === resultadoDeseado? ${encoded2 === resultadoDeseado}`);

//resultado deseado
console.log(resultadoDeseado);
```

Ninguno de los dos métodos dio el resultado esperado, y es que el primero no hizo nada, y el segundo puso secuencias de escape donde no las había antes.

Para solucionar esto, vamos a aplicar secuencias de escape a los valores que lo requieren. En este caso tenemos una cadena del tipo `key=value`, por lo tanto debemos aplicar la codificación sobre cada elemento de tipo `value` en la cadena.

Una forma sería la siguiente:

```js
let resultadoDeseado = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11%3A11%3A11%2B00%3A00&UserID=look%40me.com&Version=1.0';

let cadena = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11:11:11+00:00&UserID=look@me.com&Version=1.0';

let array = cadena.split('&');

let encodedArray = array.map(element => {
  let key = element.split('=')[0];
  let value = encodeURIComponent(element.split('=')[1]);
  return key.concat('=').concat(value);
});

let encoded = encodedArray.join('&');

console.log(encoded);
console.log(resultadoDeseado);
console.log(`¿Es encoded === resultadoDeseado? ${encoded === resultadoDeseado}`);
```

Con esto ya podemos aplicar de forma segura el método `hash` a la cadena que hemos codificado usando `encodeURIComponent` aplicado sobre cada elemento de tipo `value` en la cadena.

El resultado sería:

```js
let cadena = 'Action=FeedList&Format=XML&Timestamp=2015-07-01T11:11:11+00:00&UserID=look@me.com&Version=1.0';

let array = cadena.split('&');
let encodedArray = array.map(element => {
  let key = element.split('=')[0];
  let value = encodeURIComponent(element.split('=')[1]);
  return key.concat('=').concat(value);
});

let encoded = encodedArray.join('&');

const clave = 'b1bdb357ced10fe4e9a69840cdd4f0e9c03d77fe';
let firma = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encoded, clave);
let base64 = firma.toString(CryptoJS.enc.hex);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `<small>${base64}</small>`;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha256-6rXZCnFzbyZ685/fMsqoxxZz/QZwMnmwHg+SsNe+C/w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center" id="output"><div>
```

De esta forma el resultado obtenido es el mismo que en PHP cuando **no se usa `rawurldecode`** sobre la cadena a le que le aplicamos el `hash`. Es decir cuando tanto en PHP como en Javascript las cadenas están codificadas.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y aclare tus dudas.

Comment: Genial, gracias Mauricio por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme